# Constant Expression Parameters

Tags: c++, bitset, constant-expression

I have a function that creates a `std::bitset`, whose length is a constant function parameter. It doesn't work because the constant isn't an "integral constant expression". Is there any way I can make this work?

For reference:

```
void Foo(const std::string &data, const unsigned int size) {
    std::bitset<size> Bar(data);
    // Do something
    return;
}
```

Comment: You could make Foo into a template function and make size a non-type parameter. size has to be known at compile time otherwise this can't work.

Comment: No, not with `std::bitset`. It requires a *compile-time* constant. You could use `vector<bool>`, or [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) or similar.

Comment: I thought so. I really like my `bitset`s because I can perform bitwise logical operations and single-bit logical operations with them but if it can't be done, it can't be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a `std::bitset` needs to be evaulable at compile time. You can either make it *big enough* (in case you know the maximum size that you may need) or use another alternative, like `boost::dynamic_bitset` as Igor Tandetnik suggested.

Comment: Yes, I do know the maximum size I need but the implementation I want still depends on the size so I'll go with the `boost::dynamic_bitset`. Thanks